# Got "Unable to load the requested file: Home\home.php" Error when I upload my codeigniter site on subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am new to `codeIgniter framework`, When I uploaded codeigniter website on linux server on a sub domain It gives the `error` "`Unable to load the requested file: Home\home.php`" but working fine on my local windows machine, I have checked the case sensitivity issue but those all are fine, also I have checked the `.htaccess` file but no success. any suggestion.

here is my controller "home.php":

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->template->set('nav', 'home');
    $this->load->model('Home_model', 'home');
}

public function index()
{

    $this->template->set('title', 'Books Bazaar : Home');
    $this->template->load('template', 'Home\home');
}

?>
```

and my .htaccess file contains :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

domain where I have uploaded the site is :
    http://books.atntechnologies.com/

Thanks

Comment: Your Home class definition is missing the closing brace. I don't know if that could lead CodeIgniter to consider the file missing.

Comment: what is in your `route.php` ?

Comment: @prashant what is your base url in `config.php`...

Comment: @Charlie in my route.php there is default controller difined as ::     $route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: @sAnS in my config file base url is blank,  $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: @prashant can you add `http://books.atntechnologies.com/` as base url and check..

Comment: @sAnS I h've changed the base_url and check, but still the same error.

Comment: have you tried `/` instead of `\\`

Comment: @prashant try changing this `$this->template->load('template', 'Home\home');` to `$this->template->load('template', 'Home/home');`..

Comment: great @sAnS it works, really thanks for you valuable time, please can you explain the reason why this '\' was working on local but not on live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how codeigniter checks your file

```
function load($tpl_view, $body_view = null, $data = null) 
{
   if ( ! is_null( $body_view ) ) 
   {
      if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$tpl_view.'/'.$body_view ) ) 
      {
         $body_view_path = $tpl_view.'/'.$body_view;
      }
      else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$tpl_view.'/'.$body_view.'.php' ) ) 
      {
         $body_view_path = $tpl_view.'/'.$body_view.'.php';
      }
      else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$body_view ) ) 
      {
         $body_view_path = $body_view;
      }
      else if ( file_exists( APPPATH.'views/'.$body_view.'.php' ) ) 
      {
         $body_view_path = $body_view.'.php';
      }
      else
      {
         show_error('Unable to load the requested file: ' . $tpl_name.'/'.$view_name.'.php');
      }

      $body = $this->ci->load->view($body_view_path, $data, TRUE);

      if ( is_null($data) ) 
      {
         $data = array('body' => $body);
      }
      else if ( is_array($data) )
      {
         $data['body'] = $body;
      }
      else if ( is_object($data) )
      {
         $data->body = $body;
      }
   }

   $this->ci->load->view('templates/'.$tpl_view, $data);
}
```

so you need `'/'` instead of `'\'` for `$this->template->load('template', 'Home\home');`